# Export directly to pdf

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports-2008

I am using two stored procedures, one for main report and another for subreport. Below is the code.

```
 private void LoadSalesOrderReport()
 {
     string Type = gvQuotationDetails.Rows[QuoteIndex].Cells["Type"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
     FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMP_IMG_PATH"].ToString() + "\\" + ValQuoteID.ToString() + ".pdf";
     DeleteExistingFile(FilePath);
     try
     {
         AccountsPayableMaster objAPM = new AccountsPayableMaster();
         QuotationReport obj = new QuotationReport();
         objReportDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\rptQuotationReport.rpt");
         obj.crysQuotationReport.LogOnInfo = objAPM.ConnectionDetails("SD_SalesOrderReport;1");
         obj.crysQuotationReport.LogOnInfo = objAPM.ConnectionDetails("SD_GetBatchReportDetails;1");
         obj.crysQuotationReport.ReportSource = objReportDocument;
         objReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@QuoteID", ValQuoteID);
         objReportDocument.SetParameterValue("Type", "-" + Type.ToUpper() + "-");
         objReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@QuoteID", ValQuoteID, objReportDocument.Subreports[0].Name.ToString());
         string[] Print = objAPM.GetPrintDetails();
         SetPrintParameters(objReportDocument, Print);
         obj.Show();
         objReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, FilePath);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     OpenPdfFile();
 }

 private void OpenPdfFile()
 {
     try
     {
         Process.Start(FilePath);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please install MicrosoftOffice/Pdf Reader to view files", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     }
 }
```

The code is working fine.But the problem is. when i click the button in front end to show the pdf directly.The crystal report form is also displayed and I know the reason as I am using **obj.Show** in my code.I tried to comment it but it throws an error.Can any one advise changes in my code to directly display the pdf and not the crystalreport form.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get when you comment out obj.Show() You should be able to render the PDF to disk (using your ExportToDisk command()) and then do a Response.Redirect to the full path of the PDF file for viewing/download, depending on the client.

Comment: Hi Dillie, I am using winform not web.When I am commenting out obj.show(). It says in correct logon parameters. I have updated the question with the screenshot of the error.

Comment: You are able to generate pdf right? is the pdf in binary format?

Comment: No it is not in binary format.